# MySQL Stored procedure Need to compare 2 columns with different collation sequences

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, unicode, where-clause, collation

I have a MySql stored procedure like so

```
CREATE DEFINER=`uwcrossword`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_UpdCodePage`(IN in_id int, 
IN nm varchar(25), IN nis varchar(25), IN lang varchar(25), 
IN stpt varchar(5), IN endpt varchar(5))
BEGIN
UPDATE `uwcrossword`.`CODEPAGE`
SET
`ID` = in_id,
`Name` = nm,
`NameInScript` = nis,
`Language` = lang,
`StartPoint` = stpt,
`EndPoint` = endpt
WHERE [`ID` = in_id COLLATE utf8-general-ci] 
AND [Language = lang COLLATE utf8-unicode-ci];
END
```

`ID` column has no specific collation.  `Language` Column has collation `utf8-unicode-ci`.

#### ERROR I GET

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[`ID` = in_id COLLATE utf8-general-ci] AND [Language = lang COLLATE utf8-unicode' at line 11

When I try to run the same without any collation information

```
CREATE DEFINER=`uwcrossword`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_UpdCodePage`(IN in_id int, 
IN nm varchar(25), IN nis varchar(25), IN lang varchar(25), 
IN stpt varchar(5), IN endpt varchar(5))
BEGIN
UPDATE `uwcrossword`.`CODEPAGE`
SET
`ID` = in_id,
`Name` = nm,
`NameInScript` = nis,
`Language` = lang,
`StartPoint` = stpt,
`EndPoint` = endpt
WHERE [`ID` = in_id] 
AND [Language = lang];
END
```

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[`ID` = in_id ] 
>       AND [Language = lang]' at line 13

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [Expression Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/expressions.html), the ***`simple_expr`*** grammar production can produce `(expr [, expr] ...)`.  Note that the brackets are round, not square.

However, in this case brackets are not necessary:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`uwcrossword`@`%` PROCEDURE sp_UpdCodePage(
  IN in_id INT,
  IN nm    VARCHAR(25),
  IN nis   VARCHAR(25),
  IN lang  VARCHAR(25), 
  IN stpt  VARCHAR(5),
  IN endpt VARCHAR(5)
)

  UPDATE uwcrossword.CODEPAGE
  SET    ID           = in_id,
         Name         = nm,
         NameInScript = nis,
         Language     = lang,
         StartPoint   = stpt,
         EndPoint     = endpt
  WHERE  ID           = in_id COLLATE utf8-general-ci
     AND Language     = lang  COLLATE utf8-unicode-ci

;
```

Comment: Thanks @eggyal I realised the error could be avoided by not getting into comparing two columns with dfferent collations.  Earlier I had added a unique index on the Language column that made me add that for comparison. I removed that unique key and now need to compare only the id column.

Comment: `INT` has no collation, so that is unnecessary on `ID = in_id`.

Comment: @RickJames: Good spot!  I just blindly copied from the question.